# Magento change prices globally, using division

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento shop that I have developed for a customer. The shop is Australian and the products need to be GST inclusive. However The customer has entered all prices in the product view as GST inclusive (not exclusive) so when we go to add GST (10%) it will add a further 10%, meaning the price is above what it should be.

I have seen that there are many plugins that will do a global price change however these plugins will only allow + or - percentages. To work out the GST exclusive price I will need to ***divide by 1.1***.

Does anyone no of an extension that will allow me to divide all prices globally?
***or***
Does anybody know how I could change all prices globally programatically?

Thanks in Advance,
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin you can actually specify whether prices entered include tax or not. Just go to `System -> Configuration -> Tax -> Calculation Settings`. There you can find dropdowns for `Catalog Prices` and `Shipping Prices`, etc.